# Debugging a Fortran program using Emacs (on MacOS)

Tags: macos, debugging, emacs, fortran, gdb

I am trying to debug a fortran program within Emacs using GDB. My compiler is intel fortran 2017.4. The problem is with a particular subroutine which inverts a matrix. The program runs without a problem when the size of the matrix is "small" i.e. 100x100. When I increase the size of the matrix to, for example 600x600, I get the following message: "Thread 3 received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault."

Now, if I try to debug the program launching GDB from the terminal, everything works fine. I strongly prefer to debug the program from within Emacs since it would save me a lot of time. Any ideas about how can I fix this issue?

I already try to increase the stack size to the max (which is 65532 for MAC) and all the arrays are allocated on the heap.

Thanks for your help,

Comment: 1. How do you launch GDB in Emacs?

Comment: 2. It might help if you post what versions of Emacs, Emacs debugger packages, and GDB you use.

Answer (score 2):

> Now, if I try to debug the program launching GDB from the terminal, everything works fine.

It appears that your program does not crash when run from GDB (whether GDB is invoked from within Emacs or from a terminal), in which case your references to Emacs are superfluous.

Some of the reasons why a program may not crash under GDB are listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8345664/50617).